# Function that give me all date list of a month

Tags: r, function, date

Is there a function that could list me all dates in a specified month(year)

that is:

```
proper_function("January",2019)
```

result is

```
 [1] "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04" "2019-01-05" "2019-01-06" "2019-01-07"
 [8] "2019-01-08" "2019-01-09" "2019-01-10" "2019-01-11" "2019-01-12" "2019-01-13" "2019-01-14"
[15] "2019-01-15" "2019-01-16" "2019-01-17" "2019-01-18" "2019-01-19" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-21"
[22] "2019-01-22" "2019-01-23" "2019-01-24" "2019-01-25" "2019-01-26" "2019-01-27" "2019-01-28"
[29] "2019-01-29" "2019-01-30" "2019-01-31"
```

I could write a simple program since except for Feb each month has fixed dates for any year, but I suppose there should be some exist function in some basic packages

Comment: Try `proper_function<-function(month,year) {x<-as.Date(paste(1:31,month,year),"%d %b %Y");x[!is.na(x)]}`.

Comment: I think I got you idea by remove NA for those invalid date for a month, but %b may be changed to %B to fulfill my original info "January" not "Jan" @nicola

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should not be difficult to write one. Using only base R you can do

```
proper_function <- function(month, year) {
   start <- as.Date(paste0("01", month,year), "%d%B%Y")
   end <- seq(start, length.out = 2, by = "month")[2]
   seq(start, end - 1, by  = "day")
}

proper_function("June",2019)
# [1] "2019-06-01" "2019-06-02" "2019-06-03" "2019-06-04" "2019-06-05"....  
#     "2019-06-25" "2019-06-26" "2019-06-27" "2019-06-28" "2019-06-29" "2019-06-30"

proper_function("February",2019)
#[1] "2019-02-01" "2019-02-02" "2019-02-03" "2019-02-04" "2019-02-05" ....
#    "2019-02-25" "2019-02-26" "2019-02-27" "2019-02-28"
```

You can decide the format your input is going to take and change the `format` option in `as.Date` accordingly.

Comment: So you get initial date from my info then find the first date of next month, thus get the end point of this month, then get the seq according to the first and last date of the month, the idea is clear~ The key method is the second line which save you from figure out how many dates each month have, If there is no direct method, I think this one works

Comment: @cloudscomputes you can optimise(?) a little or save a few keystrokes to get `end` using `month` from `lubridate` but I am not aware of a direct function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the lubridate package. You just have to provide the month in the following format:

```
proper_function <- function(x) {
  x <- as_date(x)
  y <- days_in_month(x)
  as_date(1:y, origin = x-1)
}
x <- c("2012-02-01")
proper_function(x)
 [1] "2012-02-01" "2012-02-02" "2012-02-03" "2012-02-04" "2012-02-05" "2012-02-06" "2012-02-07" "2012-02-08"
 [9] "2012-02-09" "2012-02-10" "2012-02-11" "2012-02-12" "2012-02-13" "2012-02-14" "2012-02-15" "2012-02-16"
[17] "2012-02-17" "2012-02-18" "2012-02-19" "2012-02-20" "2012-02-21" "2012-02-22" "2012-02-23" "2012-02-24"
[25] "2012-02-25" "2012-02-26" "2012-02-27" "2012-02-28" "2012-02-29"
```